# how to send single quotes and special characters in curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a curl hit, that is something like:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/market/products/' -d '{
    "description": \"If you and your husband or boyfriend like to wear things that match; and he wears frame model 189812 or 189832; or the Unisex frame models 187821 or 187812; you've got to get this full-rim; round; medium-size; faux-wood; hypoallergenic acetate Women's eyeglasses frame. The male and female versions of these glasses are similar; although these are actually a little bigger than the male model. (We're talking about your guy; so don't start thinking about male models; unless he is one.) One version is brown; the other is purple; and the two of you will look adorable in your matching glasses. If you're single; you won't be for long (if that's your desire); because you'll look adorable in these glasses all by yourself!\"" }'
```

Now my problem is with the special characters in the description field. Can any one suggest me what should I do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double all your single quotes (i.e. `you''ll` instead of `you'll`) and remove the first backslash in the description field, like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/market/products/' -d '{    "description": "If you and your husband or boyfriend like to wear things that match; and he wears frame model 189812 or 189832; or the Unisex frame models 187821 or 187812; you''ve got to get this full-rim; round; medium-size; faux-wood; hypoallergenic acetate Women''s eyeglasses frame. The male and female versions of these glasses are similar; although these are actually a little bigger than the male model. (We''re talking about your guy; so don''t start thinking about male models; unless he is one.) One version is brown; the other is purple; and the two of you will look adorable in your matching glasses. If you''re single; you won''t be for long (if that''s your desire); because you''ll look adorable in these glasses all by yourself!\"" }'
                                                                             ^
                                                                             |
                                                           remove the backslash here
```